# Multiple Connected Sliders with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a set number of controls that are a value between 1 and 100. The entire set of these sliders must total 100. I would like to use a series slider for this control, and I would like to connect them (i.e. when one slider moves, the others adjust).

I remember seeing a website (I believe it was humblebundle.com) that had this functionality. I can't seem to find any examples of this.

Is there a plugin that will do what I want, or do I have to write something myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres an example like this here: [Combined total for multiple jQuery-UI Sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486371/combined-total-for-multiple-jquery-ui-sliders)

I dont think it's exactly what you're looking for but it might be a good start :)

Comment: That's actually really close to what I need. Thanks, I think I can make this work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question here: [Jquery Interconnected slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262003/jquery-interconnected-slider)  which I posted my solution on.

Just a quick rehash of that post: I have a quick library on [Github - jQuery Interconnected Sliders](https://github.com/gburtini/jquery-interconnected-sliders) that does exactly this. See my other answer for more information. :)

Comment: your other post isn't a solution because it don't show how you implement it.