# 3 jquery ui slider connected

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I try to connect 3 jquery ui sliders.

The sum of the 3 values must always stay at 100, so when a slider is moved the two others must moved.

I made something, it works but it is very slow: http://jsfiddle.net/vBsTR/2/

If you just connect one slider it works fine (try to move the first one): http://jsfiddle.net/tyjJx/2/

Can anyone help please?
Thanks!

Comment: It's very slow? There is infinite recursion so it doesn't even run ;o

Comment: Put somewhere the 'PANIC' button into your Fiddle before posting ;)

Comment: I updated the second link, it works fine..
What is this PANIC button?

Comment: It works quite decently for me if I just remove the slidechange event bindings.

Comment: You're right! if we just drag & drop the handle it works fine!
http://jsfiddle.net/vBsTR/3/
But it doesn't work if you click on the slider's background..

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this as well and ended up writing it from scratch

http://jsbin.com/ojeruc/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You may check [event.originalEvent](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-change) before your refresh function:

```
event.originalEvent && (event.originalEvent.type == 'mousemove' || event.originalEvent.type == 'mouseup') && refreshSliders(1);
```

> Use event.originalEvent to detect whether the value changed by mouse, keyboard, or programmatically.

This is your example [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/tyjJx/3/)

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand why it didn't work.. Everything is OK now, but I can see one more problem, if you click on the slider's background to change the value sometimes the total is bigger than 100.. http://jsfiddle.net/tyjJx/7/

Comment: @pol your example seem to work only from 2 to 2 increments. What if you have 10 sliders? Not sure the solution is very scalable.