# jQuery slider with locking and total of 100

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I have been working on a tool like https://github.com/gburtini/jquery-interconnected-sliders as mentioned at [Jquery Interconnected slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262003/jquery-interconnected-slider).

I tried to contact the author, but didn't get a response so I tried to implement the same using https://github.com/kbwood/linkedsliders for linking my sliders.

The linking and totalling works fine, but I wanted to introduce locking as well; again I tried to contact the author without any success.

Now I am a little close to creating it, but am a little stuck.

The problem is

The after the max value being set, it should block the slider to slide beyond the max value, I have something of this working at [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/vksvicky/an52rj98/7/)

At times it does not work; can you please help me correct it.

If you slide and lock and see you can find when it does not work, its a difficult to explain.

Update 01: My custom linkedslider is available at http://yourjavascript.com/14831410408/jquery-linkedsliders.js

Comment: Post your code in your question please. You saw the warning when you tried to post your question and attempted to circumvent it by highlight a word as code.

Comment: @j08691, The warning came up when I was trying to post the link to jsfiddle, so I wrapped into a word and it has a hyperlink. And the code is html & js so isn't it easier to see it working?

Comment: You can see it working just fine here by using the [stack snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) feature. If any of the sites you linked to are inaccessible, then your question loses all value.

Comment: @j08691, thanks for the info, didn't realise it. I tried to use it  and nothing happened when I clicked post it. Any idea?