# How do I create a dynamic set of slider bars

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm well-versed in HMTL/CSS but lean heavily on ready-made jQuery solutions to accomplish some more advanced interactions. I'm looking to create a set of sliders similar to what is done on the [Humble Indie Budle](http://www.humblebundle.com/) payment distribution section. I need several slider bars that will total 100% and as you move them the others adjust in real-time. I check the HIB source but it looks like custom JS and I don't want to lift it outright. Anyone know of any available JS or jQuery resources that might help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you okay with using HTML5 sliders?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combined total for multiple jQuery-UI Sliders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486371/combined-total-for-multiple-jquery-ui-sliders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Here's a start](http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/Y5ZLL/4/)**

I'm pretty sure can modify it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This should be worth trying http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Just select 'multiple sliders' in right menu.