# Multiple jQuery sliders with master one which is controlled by them and can control latter as well

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

First of all sorry for my poor english AND jQuery.

So what i am trying to do? Here is what i am imagining:

**Master**

------------------------------------||---------------------------------------

Other                                                       Other2

-------||-----------                                       ----------||----------

Other3                                                       Other4

-------||-----------                                       ----------||----------

Master max value = 1200

Other max value = 100

Other1 max value = 400

Other2 max value = 200

Other3 max value = 500

(all Others sum is 1200)

Moving master slider, all Other sliders values are increasing respectively.
Moving each Other slider, Master one increases the same.

What can you recommend for me?

I read those, but there was just a little use:

[Combined total for multiple jQuery-UI Sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486371/combined-total-for-multiple-jquery-ui-sliders)

[JQuery UI Slider - Combined Max for multiple sliders that also have individual max values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360246/jquery-ui-slider-combined-max-for-multiple-sliders-that-also-have-individual-m)

Hope my point was clear.

Can someone help me? JSFiddle would be the best answer...

**Update: added JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trajektorijus/AS8Xk/56/

Good day to all,

Tadas

Comment: at least start the fiddle and get the sliders set up

Comment: Thank you for your remark. Just added JSFiddle! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/bv8g8/

It updates the master when you change all the other sliders and when you update the master it updates all the others.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you a lot my friend. But one more thing. When i adjust Other slider, value on right doesn't increase. How can we fix that?