# Jquery range slider compatibility for 3 values selections in range 0-100

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider

I would like to use [jquery slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) to adjust values between 0 and 100, and divide them with percentages

value 1 
value 2
and value 3 can be each between 0-90 while the others can't be less than 5,
let's thinks about the following values 33,33,34.

the slider should show 3 values and there should be option to move between the values (attached an image)
i used [jquery slider range](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range), but it is not supporting 33,33 option, i attached the code (i am using angular directive but it's jquery so it looks the same)

[image]

if you have any idea how to help me fix this issue

or advice for another component that doing what i need

**CODE:**

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
range: true,
min: 0,
max: 100,
values: [ $scope.rangeLeft, $scope.rangeRight ],
slide: function( event, ui ) {

    var left = ui.values[0];
    var center = ui.values[1];
    var right = 100 - Math.abs(Math.round(left + center));

    if (left  < 5 || left  > 95 ||
        center  < 5 || center  > 95 ||
        right  < 5 || right  > 95 ||
        left + center  >  95 ||
        center + right  > 95)
    {
        console.log(left + " " + center + " " + right);
        return false;
    }

    $("#slider-range-left").text(left + '%');
    $("#slider-range-center").text(center + '%');
    $("#slider-range-right").text(right + '%');
    console.log(left + " " + center + " " + right);
}
```

Comment: angular js and jquery are two different things, usage of both is not recommended, as it would result in overkill

Comment: @dreamweiver What you said is utterly stupid. I have seen many projects using both these frameworks. Mind that AngularJS is a MVC framework while jQuery makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler.

Comment: @Liad Livnat Please add a fiddle.

Comment: @Foreever: refer to point number 2 over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background . it clearly states augmenting jquery with angular.js is not recommended as it will be a overkill.

Comment: guys you are missing the point, the point wasn't angularjs with jquery i already tested several directives myself before doing it, the question was if you understand how can i accomplish 3 values choose from slider range

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486371/combined-total-for-multiple-jquery-ui-sliders