# Multiple jquery-ui sliders with a set range limit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, range

I am attempting to setup multiple groups of jquery-ui sliders on a page. Each group is to be configured to have a set range limit. The code below (found from [Combined total for multiple jQuery-UI Sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486371/combined-total-for-multiple-jquery-ui-sliders?rq=1) ) works as intended if there is a single group of sliders on the page.

The issues arise when there are multiple groups of sliders on a single page. When there are multiple sliders the second group set appears to follow the limit rules along with the last selected slider from the first group. The first group does not appear to follow any limits for its group of sliders.

Script Code below:

```
var uls = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
for(var i=0;i<uls.length;i++){
if(uls[i].id.indexOf('sliders')==0){

var sliders = $("#sliders" +i+ " .slider");

var size = 1000;
var size_step = 100;

sliders.each(function() {
var value = parseInt($(this).text(), size_step),
  availableTotal = size;

$(this).empty().slider({
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: size,
  range: "max",
  step: size_step,
  animate: 100,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    // Update display to current value
    $(this).siblings().text(ui.value);

    // Get current total
    var total = 0;

    sliders.not(this).each(function() {
      total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
    });

    // Need to do this because apparently jQ UI
    // does not update value until this event completes
    total += ui.value;
    var max = availableTotal - total;

    // Update each slider
    sliders.not(this).each(function() {
      var t = $(this),
      value = t.slider("option", "value");

      t.slider("option", "max", max + value)
        .siblings().text(value + '/' + (max + value));
      t.slider('value', value);
    });
  }
});
});
}
}
```

Page code listed below:

```
Slider 1
<ul id="sliders0">
<li>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <span class="value">0</span>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <span class="value">0</span>
</li>
</ul>
<br><br>
Slider 2
<ul id="sliders1">
<li>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <span class="value">0</span>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <span class="value">0</span>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <span class="value">0</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have setup a jsfiddle of my code and a example with two groups of sliders at:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZLL/1640/

Answer (score 0):

I made this plugin a few days ago. It supports multiple sets of groups:
https://github.com/jhovgaard/jquery.rangegroup