# Multiple HTML Input tags of type range that always add up to a specific value?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to have multiple HTML Input tags of type range that always add up to a specific value. Here is my current code:

```
<label>Slider 1
    <input max="1.0" min="-1.0" step="0.05" type="range" value="1.0">
</label>
<label>Slider 2
    <input max="1.0" min="-1.0" step="0.05" type="range" value="0.0">
</label>
<label>Slider 3
    <input max="1.0" min="-1.0" step="0.05" type="range" value="0.0">
</label>
<label>Slider 4
    <input max="1.0" min="-1.0" step="0.05" type="range" value="0.0">
</label>
```

I would like to have it so that if one slider moves the rest are adjusted so that the tally/sum always is 1. I don't mind using JavaScript (however it would be preferable not to), but I do not want to use jQuery, jQuery-UI, or other external libraries, which this similar question asks about: [Combined total for multiple jQuery-UI Sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486371/combined-total-for-multiple-jquery-ui-sliders)

Comment: Do you mean if you adjust one slider, take its difference from 1 and randomly assign that between the other sliders?

Comment: @traktor53 I want them to do their best to evenly distribute; if 4th is moved by the value 0,15, move 1, 2, and 3 by -0,05. If slider n is moved by 0,05, move slider (n + 1) % 4 by -0,05. If slider n is moved by 0,10, move sliders (n + 1) % 4 and (n + 2) % 4 by -0,05. Does that make sense? Though, that said, if there is a built-in HTML way to do this that does not follow this exact algorithm I'm okay with that too provided the user experience is good.

Comment: There is no built in HTML or JavaScript way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

we'll use plain JS to make this work. The first thing you want to add is an `onchange` attribute to your sliders so it triggers a given function that will update the other sliders. We have to give this function the index of the slider we just changed. Let give the sliders indexes between 0 and 3. Give them an ID so we'll be able to change them in the JS script. Let's call the function `change()`.

So let's write the function now.
What we want to do is to change the other sliders value. The initial sum is one so let's keep that value forever. We need to store the values in an array so we'll be able to see what the change was. So when a slider was changed, calculate the delta between the new value and the old one. Once you know how the change affected the total sum, let's change the other sliders thanks to the delta we just calculated. Since there's 3 sliders we can change, add them the third of the delta to each slider. This way, the change made on one slider will be "cancelled" in the total sum so we keep the initial, which was 1.

Here's how your code should look like now :

```js
let values = [1, 0, 0, 0]; // The initial values

  /* The onchange attribute will trigger this function */
  function change(x) {

    let newValue = document.getElementById(String(x)).value * 1; // Find the new value
    let oldValue = values[x]; // Search for the old value
    
    values[x] = newValue; // Update in the array the new value
    let deltaValue = oldValue - newValue; // Calculate the difference between the old value and the new one

    /* Now, loop through all the buttons to update them */
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if(i === x) continue; // If it's the same, so do not change a thing
      
      /* This is the new value we want to put in
       * We want to equilibrate the whole system
       * Means we have to update the 3 other sliders
       * So just add to each one of them the third of the difference created by the one changed
       */
      
      let newVal = document.getElementById(String(i)).value * 1 + deltaValue / 3; // * 1 is to convert the value into an number, we do not want a String
      document.getElementById(String(i)).value = newVal; // Put the new value in
      values[i] += deltaValue / 3; // And update that value in the array
    }
  }
```

```html
<label>Slider 1
    <input onchange="change(0)" id="0" max="1.0" min="-1.0" step="0.05" type="range" value="1.0">
</label>
<label>Slider 2
    <input onchange="change(1)" id="1" max="1.0" min="-1.0" step="0.05" type="range" value="0.0">
</label>
<label>Slider 3
    <input onchange="change(2)" id="2" max="1.0" min="-1.0" step="0.05" type="range" value="0.0">
</label>
<label>Slider 4
    <input onchange="change(3)" id="3" max="1.0" min="-1.0" step="0.05" type="range" value="0.0">
</label>
```

I'm pretty sure there's a lot of optimizing that can be done but since I'm not a JS expert, that shall do it !

Hope this helped you.

Comment: While this is neat, it does not seem to guarantee that the total sum is 1. Thank you anyway.